# "A newer version of phpMyAdmin is available..." Warning doesn't disappear after upgrade

Tags: phpmyadmin, warnings

I just now upgraded phpMyAdmin to 4.2.2 on my XAMPP install. I've closed and restarted the services but the homepage of phpMyAdmin continues to display this message at the bottom of the page:

***"A newer version of phpMyAdmin is available and you should consider upgrading. The newest version is 4.2.2, released on 2014-05-20."***

I followed the install procedure found [here](http://neo-tutorial.blogspot.com/2011/05/upgrading-phpmyadmin-in-xampp-for.html).

The main page of phpMyAdmin also shows this: http://postimg.org/image/ovtfzwb59/

![enter image description here][2]

Which I'm using to safely assume that the upgrade did work but that I'm missing a step for that warning to go away. How can I get rid of that warning? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Force refresh your browser and/or delete cookies and temp internet files.